# What if object gets released before the completion of its method execution

Tags: iphone, core-data, release, popviewcontroller, performselector

I have an viewController that fires a web service get some data and stores the result in core data after parsing in a different thread..

I have a lot of data so parsing will take some time and am not sure if popping the viewController in navigation will stop the execution of my parsing method,

if it stops the execution in between then my core data DB will get corrupted so does it stops the execution or perform the selector before releasing my viewController object

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc performSelectorInBackground:aSelector withObject:arg];
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, where is `MyViewController` released? Is it autoreleased?

Comment: If the parsing is in a different thread, it shouldn't be affected.  If you have a callback or notification that goes back to your view controller when the parsing is done, that could be a problem.  If data corruption is a serious problem, you should also consider the user pressing the home button.

Comment: Nice point Phillip, I wasn't even considering that as a problem, do you have any suggestion??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider moving the web server interactions to a different object.  This object could handle the requests / responses and storing the results to Core Data.  This object might also be a global object with a queue to handle requests.  If not then you will need to handle canceling the request during your view controller dealloc.

Your view controllers can listen for changes to Core Data and take appropriate action.

Comment: and the connection thingy can keep track of inflight requests count, throttling if needed.  +1 for pointing out that core data should be observed for changes, rather than notifications or delegate (yuck!).

Comment: What do you mean by "listen for changes to Core Data", as far as i know you listen to contextdidsavenotification and take appropriate action, is there any other way??

Comment: Get a notification when Core Data changes.  [Check out this SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463950/iphone-coredata-how-can-i-track-observe-all-changes-within-a-subgraph)